# How to calculate a running total for "BundlesSent" (derived from a count function)

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I am getting the first image but need the syntax for the second.

```
         **Yvalue   Xvalue**

        **380**   04/21/2014   * # of People on 4/21/2014

          487     04/21/2014   *Total

        **68**    04/28/2014   * # of People on 4/28/2014

          487     04/28/2014    *Total

        **25**    05/05/2014    * # of People on 5/5/2014

          487     05/05/2014    *Total

         **Yvalue   Xvalue**

         **380**   04/21/2014   * # of People through 4/21/2014

           487     04/21/2014   *Total

         **448**   04/28/2014   * # of People through 4/28/2014

           487     04/28/2014   *Total

         **473**   05/05/2014   * # of People through 5/5/2014

           487     05/05/2014   *Total
```

The Yvalue and Xvalue are derived by the below code.  I am currently receiving the number of people given a certain day.  I am looking to record the number of people through a certain day.  I would like the sum of everyone between the StartDate and the Xvalue date.

```
select COUNT(contact_username) AS Yvalue ,
       convert(varchar(10) , det.sent_to_print_shop, 101 ) AS Xvalue
FROM FWIA_Bundler_Log_Bucket_Details det
WHERE convert(varchar(10),det.sent_to_print_shop,101) >= '++StartDate++'
  AND convert(varchar(10),det.sent_to_print_shop,101) <= '++EndDate++'
GROUP BY convert(varchar(10),det.sent_to_print_shop,101)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLServer 2012 or better you can use `SUM() OVER (ORDER BY)`

```
SELECT SUM(1) OVER(ORDER BY det.sent_to_print_shop) AS Yvalue ,
       convert(varchar(10) , det.sent_to_print_shop, 101 ) AS Xvalue
FROM   FWIA_Bundler_Log_Bucket_Details det
WHERE  convert(varchar(10),det.sent_to_print_shop,101) >= '++StartDate++'
  AND  convert(varchar(10),det.sent_to_print_shop,101) <= '++EndDate++'
GROUP BY convert(varchar(10),det.sent_to_print_shop,101)
```

if you are using an older version of SQLServer to do the running total you need a self join

```
SELECT COUNT(c.contact_username) AS Yvalue ,
       convert(varchar(10) , det.sent_to_print_shop, 101 ) AS Xvalue
FROM   FWIA_Bundler_Log_Bucket_Details det
       INNER JOIN FWIA_Bundler_Log_Bucket_Details c 
          ON det.sent_to_print_shop >= c.det.sent_to_print_shop
WHERE  convert(varchar(10),det.sent_to_print_shop,101) >= '++StartDate++'
  AND  convert(varchar(10),det.sent_to_print_shop,101) <= '++EndDate++'
GROUP BY convert(varchar(10),det.sent_to_print_shop,101)
```

The idea is sound, but the queries are untested, they may need some tweaking

Comment: I will try to mess with the above query.  As is I am getting incorrect numbers for each date:479, 481 & 483 instead of 380, 448 & 473.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running SQL Server 2012, you can do this using windowing functions. Given this table:

```
id dtSubmitted             userName cnt
-- ----------------------- -------- ---
 1 2014-01-01 14:23:00.000 john      10
 2 2014-01-01 15:23:00.000 sally     15
 3 2014-01-01 16:45:00.000 abe        5
 4 2014-01-02 10:00:00.000 mac       25
 5 2014-01-02 12:43:00.000 hector     5
 6 2014-01-02 17:54:00.000 emily     75
 7 2014-01-03 14:42:00.000 emily    125
 8 2014-01-03 19:58:00.000 meg       75
```

You can say

```
select DateSubmitted = convert(date,t.dtSubmitted) ,
       Total         = sum( t.cnt ) ,
       RunningTotal  = sum( sum(t.cnt) ) over (
                         order by convert(date,t.dtSubmitted)
                         rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                         )
from foo t
group by convert(date,t.dtSubmitted)
order by 1
```

To see this:

```
DateSubmitted Total RunningTotal
------------- ----- ------------
2014-01-01       30           30
2014-01-02      105          135
2014-01-03      200          335
```

In your case, the query would look something like this:

```
declare @StartDate date = '++StartDate++'
declare @EndDate   date = '++EndDate++'

select [Date]       = convert(date,t.sent_to_print_shop) ,
       Total        = count( t.contact_user_name ) ,
       RunningTotal = sum(count( t.contact_user_name )) over (
                        order by convert(date,t.sent_to_print_shop)
                        rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                        )
from FWIA_Bundler_Log_Bucket_Details t
where t.sent_to_print_shop >= @StartDate
  and t.sent_to_print_shop <  @EndDate
group by convert(date,t.sent_to_print_shop)
```

**Edited To Note...***

Supposedly if you've got SQL Server 2008 R2, something like the following should work (emphasis on the *should*, as I don't have a 2008 R2 instance to play with):

```
select DateSubmitted = d.DateSubmitted ,
       Total         = d.Total ,
       RunningTotal  = sum( d.Total ) over ( order by convert(date,t.dtSubmitted) )
from ( select DateSubmitted = convert(date,t.dtSubmitted) ,
              Total         = sum( t.cnt )
       from foo t
       group by convert(date,t.dtSubmitted)
     ) d
order by d.DateSubmitted
```

The other technique would be to use a correlated subquery, something like this:

```
with
daily_summary as
(
  select DateSubmitted = convert(date,dtSubmitted) ,
         Total         = sum(cnt)
  from foo
)
select DateSubmitted = curr.DateSubmitted ,
       Total         = curr.Total         ,
       Rollup        = sum( prev.Total )
from daily_summary curr
join daily_summary prev on prev.DateSubmitted <= curr.DateSubmitted
group by curr.DateSubmitted , curr.Total
order by curr.DateSubmitted
```

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately i am using SQL Server 2008 and am receiving an error message for the above script.

Comment: @user3657970: edited answer to include some other approaches.